# Angular 5 + Firebase: Namespace 'firebase.auth' has no exported member 'IdTokenResult'

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angular5, google-cloud-functions, angular-cli-v6

I am currently work on web project using Angular 5 and I want to integrate the Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notification on app, bt I faced to a lot of problems that I tried to fix them. Right now there two errors that I'm not able to fix concerning: `Namespace 'firebase.auth'` and `functions`

The errors look like:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts(12,45): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase.auth' has no exported member 'IdTokenResult'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/gerardtalla/dev/workspaces/ws-parcaune/pms/pms-frontend-2018/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.
```

How can I fix that? I'm using

***Angular 5***

***"firebase": "4.8.0"***

***"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5"***

***"@angular/cli": "~1.7.3"***

if someone has an idea do not hesitate please share with me. Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: what is the angular version like 5.x.x?

Comment: @haifzhan it's Angular: 5.2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is version compatible issue, you can read
[AngularFirebase2 Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

**5.0.0-rc.9 (2018-05-16)**

**auth: Adding user and idTokenResult Observables to AngularFireAuth (#1642) (31045a9)**

Answer (score 4):

just use "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.5" instead of "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5"

Comment: when I used "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.5" I got this error by running _npm install_ : _npm ERR! code ETARGET_
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.5
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'pms-frontend-2018'
npm ERR! notarget

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command:

```
npm i --save firebase@latest   angularfire2@latest
```

Comment: It will not work. It is always better to mention the package version, so in the future, app builds does not break

Answer (score 1):

"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
 "firebase": "4.9.0",

I resolve this issue by making this change in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

mostly it is the version problem

make this change in package.json

- "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
- "firebase": "4.9.0"

These should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with this.

```
"firebase": "^5.7.0",
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, remove folder in node_modules and reinstall firebase fixed my problem.

```
npm install --save firebase
```

mostly it is the version problem, check version using `npm list`, or try downgrade to the following the error should gone

- angular: 4
- angularfire2: "^5.0.0-rc.3"
- firebase: "4.13.1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 npm install --save firebase @angular/fire -f
```